# Loading Data from Google Cloud Storage to GoogleBigQuery

Tags: c#, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am uploading data from json file stored in Google Cloud to BigQUery Table but I am getting below  Error

Not found: URI gs://encoreteststorage/Myfolder/TestDataJson.json

File Location in Cloud-> Buckets/encoreteststorage/Myfolder

Is bucket URI Incorrect(Bucket Name,folder and file names are correct) or there is any other issue?

I have the permission to the bigquery dataset as I am able to upload data to BigQuery directly from my local system using BigQueryTable UploadJson Method.

CodeSnippet

```
public IEnumerable<ErrorInfo> ImportDataFromCloudStorage(string uri, WriteDisposition disposition = WriteDisposition.WriteAppend)
{
    TableReference reference = new TableReference
    {
        DatasetId = "TestDataset",
        TableId = "UploadDatafromCloud",
        ProjectId = _projectId
    };

    BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(_projectId, _googleCredential);

    BigQueryJob job = client.CreateLoadJob(uri, reference, null, new CreateLoadJobOptions()
    {

        WriteDisposition = disposition,
        SourceFormat = FileFormat.NewlineDelimitedJson,
        CreateDisposition = CreateDisposition.CreateIfNeeded
    });

    job.PollUntilCompleted();

    return CheckJobStatus(client, job.Reference);
}
```

Comment: Does the account you're using definitely have access to that file? For example, if you create a `StorageClient` using the same credential, are you able to download the file?

Comment: Hello Jon, Yes I am able to download that file using StorageClient and I have also checked the permission for the account.

Comment: Hmmm... that's odd. We have very similar code here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/master/apis/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.Snippets/BigQueryClientSnippets.cs#L845. I'll try to reproduce the issue when I can, although it's unlikely to be today, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes Jon, something weird happening here, it would be great if you can spend sometime on this issue whenever you get time.Thanx

Comment: Hmm... have just tried to reproduce it, and other than having to add "Autodetect = true" to the load options (because the table didn't exist), it worked first time. Are you able to test creating a new file in Cloud Storage (with the same account) and seeing whether that changes anything? I wonder whether that file has some unusual permissions that prevent the BigQuery service from accessing it, somehow...

Comment: Hello Jon,  I am able to execute it now . I just remove fileformat from URI and its working for me, earlier I was trying with fileformat (i.e .json)

Comment: gs://encoreteststorage/Myfolder/TestDataJson This is the URI which is working for me..

Comment: What do you mean by "fileformat"? It's not clear what URI value you used, to be honest. Still, glad it's fixed.

Comment: In that case, presumably the storage file doesn't have ".json" on the end of it - you should be able to verify that in the Storage part of the Google Cloud Platform Console.

Comment: Earlier URI gs://encoreteststorage/Myfolder/TestDataJson.json New URI gs://encoreteststorage/Myfolder/TestDataJson........I just remove .json from the URI to make it work

Comment: (I'd suggest deleting the question at this point, btw.)

Comment: Sure Jon Thanx for your time..